# How do I remove the margin-bottom of a child in the last of a set of elements?

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the `margin-bottom` of the `p` in the last container element with `.col-md-2`?

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.col-md-2 p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2-wrap">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>lorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsum</p>
    <p>lorum ipsumlorum ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</p>
    <p>lorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should I use the `nth-child` or `last-of-type` selector? I can't figure out how to use either for my situation.

Comment: Edited to attempt to tidy, though in retrospect I'm not sure whether your desire was to remove the margin for the `p` of the last `.col-md-2`, or the last `p` of each `.col-md-2`. I settled on the former, so please review the edit and revise the wording as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use twice the `last-child` selector, try this:

```
.col-md-2-wrap div:last-child p:last-child {
  margin:0;
}
```

- .col-md-2-wrap ... Target the wrapper.
- div:last-child ... Target the last `.col-md-2` inside wrapper
- p:last-child ... Target the last `p` inside that last `.col-md-2`

```css
.col-md-2-wrap {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.col-md-2 p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.next {
  background: gold;
  height: 50px;
}
.col-md-2-wrap div:last-child p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2-wrap">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>lorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsum</p>
    <p>lorum ipsumlorum ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</p>
    <p>lorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsumlorum ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="next"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just add another rule to specify "The last `p` of the last `col-md-2` should have 0 margin" like so:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.col-md-2 p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.col-md-2:last-of-type p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

If you didn't want to do this for one reason or another, you could do the following:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.col-md-2:not(:last-of-type) p, .col-md-2:last-of-type p:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

This one has two parts:

1. `.col-md-2:not(:last-of-type) p` applies the margin to all `p`'s except the ones that occur in the last `col-md-2`
2. `.col-md-2:last-of-type p:not(:last-child)` applies it to all `p`'s of the last `col-md-2` except the very last `p`.

Comment: Best and first answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-md-2:last-child > p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```